# Run all catch2 tests in one compile unit without tag definition

Tags: c++, unit-testing, catch2

I have the following project structure:

**test_main.cc**

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN

#include "catch2.hpp"
```

**test1.cc**

```
#include "catch2.hpp"

TEST_CASE("test1", "[test1]") {
  REQUIRE(1 == 1);
}
```

**test2.cc**

```
#include "catch2.hpp"

TEST_CASE("test2", "[test2]") {
  REQUIRE(2 == 2);
}
```

Now, I can run all tests with e.g. `test1` using the command line option `test1` at the runtime of the test executable.

I usually tag all test in one file with the same tags, since I use one file to combine all tests for the same topic. Thus, using a file and tags violated the `DRY` principle.

My question is there a way to run all catch2 tests defined in one file?

Comment: The concept of translation units are lost once the executable have been linked. Unless you have some other way to distinguish tests from a certain translation unit there's really no way to do it. Catch tags are probably the best and simplest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found in documentation this:

[Catch2/command-line.md at devel · catchorg/Catch2 · GitHub](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/command-line.md#filenames-as-tags)

> ### Filenames as tags
>
> -#, --filenames-as-tags
>
> When this option is used then every test is given an additional tag which is formed of the unqualified filename it is found in, with any extension stripped, prefixed with the `#` character.
>
> So, for example, tests within the file `~\Dev\MyProject\Ferrets.cpp` would be tagged `[#Ferrets]`.

Looks like [it works](https://godbolt.org/z/6T3aP4a76), so now just filter test based on that tag.

There is even [exact example in documentation](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/command-line.md#specifying-which-tests-to-run)

> ...
>
> ```
> -# [#somefile]          Matches all tests from the file 'somefile.cpp'
> ```